# Testing a Batch - Assert fails, Reference reverts to original value in Test.StopTest()

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch

I'm working on a class to update some records, but when testing it fails the `assertEquals()`

The Class that does the updating:

```
global class EscalationSkillUpdater implements Database.Batchable <sObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start (Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String DayOfWeek = System.now().format('E');
        String query;

        // Account for 24-hour time
        String AmPm = datetime.now().format().split(' ')[2];
        String StringHour;
        Integer hour = datetime.NOW().hour();

        if (AmPm == 'PM' && hour < 12)
            hour += 12;
        hour *= 100;

        if (hour < 1000)
            StringHour = '0' + hour.format();
        else
            StringHour = hour.format();

        query = 'Select Id, SkillEscalation__c, ChangeToSkillTo__c, SkillEscalation__r.ToSkill__c from SkillEscalationChangeRecord__c ';

        if (DayOfWeek == 'Sun') query += 'where Sunday__c = True ';
        else if (DayOfWeek == 'Mon') query += 'where Monday__c = True ';
        else if (DayOfWeek == 'Tue') query += 'where Tuesday__c = True ';
        else if (DayOfWeek == 'Wed') query += 'where Wednesday__c = True ';
        else if (DayOfWeek == 'Thu') query += 'where Thursday__c = True ';
        else if (DayOfWeek == 'Fri') query += 'where Friday__c = True ';
        else if (DayOfWeek == 'Sat') query += 'where Saturday__c = True ';

        query += 'and RecordType.Name = \'To Skill Change\' and Time__c = :StringHour';

        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute (Database.BatchableContext BC, list<SkillEscalationChangeRecord__c> scope) {
        for (SkillEscalationChangeRecord__c record : scope) {
            system.debug('Before assignment: ' + record.SkillEscalation__r.ToSkill__c);
            record.SkillEscalation__r.ToSkill__c = record.ChangeToSkillTo__c;
            system.debug('After assignment: ' + record.SkillEscalation__r.ToSkill__c);
        }
        update scope;
    }

    global void finish (Database.BatchableContext BC) {System.debug('FINISHED BATCHING.');}
}
```

It is supposed to find all `SkillEscalationChangeRecord__c`s for today, and this hour.  It should then assign a new `Skill__c` reference to `SkillEscalationChangeRecord__c.SkillEscalation__r.ToSkill_c`.  In `execute()` the debug statements show that the new correct value is being assigned:

[image]

However, my `AssertEquals()` is failing.  Here is the test class:

```
@isTest

public class BatchSkillExcalationUpdaterTest {
    static testMethod void ValidateUpdates() {

        RecordType WaitType =  new RecordType(Name = 'Wait Time Change');
        RecordType SkillType = new RecordType(Name = 'To Skill Change');

        SkillEscalationTemplate__c SkillTemplate = new SkillEscalationTemplate__c();
        insert SkillTemplate;

        LanguageAttribute__c SPA = new LanguageAttribute__c(name = 'Spanish', code__c = 'SPA', Description__c = 'Test Language');
        insert SPA;

        Skill__c fromSkill = new Skill__c(name = '101:SPA:L1', Language__r = SPA, Language__c = SPA.Id, SkillType__c = 'Interpreter');
        Skill__c toSkill = new Skill__c(name = '101:SPA:L2', Language__r = SPA, Language__c = SPA.Id, SkillType__c = 'Interpreter');        
        insert FromSkill;
        insert ToSkill;

        // Account for 24-hour time
        String AmPm = datetime.now().format().split(' ')[2];
        String StringTime;
        Integer hour = datetime.NOW().hour();
        if (AmPm == 'PM' && hour < 12)
            hour += 12;
        hour *= 100;

        if (hour < 1000)
            StringTime = '0' + hour.format();
        else
            StringTime = hour.format();

        SkillEscalation__c SE = new SkillEscalation__c(
                MaxWaitTime__c = 0,
                toSkill__c = fromSkill.Id, 
                SkillEscalationTemplate__c = SkillTemplate.Id);
        insert SE;

        SkillEscalationChangeRecord__c SC = new SkillEscalationChangeRecord__c(
                ChangeToSkillTo__c = ToSkill.Id,
                RecordType = SkillType,
                SkillEscalation__c = SE.Id,
                Time__c = StringTime,
                Sunday__c = True,
                Monday__c = True,
                Tuesday__c = True,
                Wednesday__c = True,
                Thursday__c = True,
                Friday__c = True,
                Saturday__c = True);
        insert SC;

        // System.debug('Before batch, before test: ' + SE.ToSkill__c);
        System.Test.startTest();
        // System.debug('Before batch, inside test: ' + SE.ToSkill__c);
        EscalationSkillUpdater SkillBatch = new EscalationSkillUpdater();    
        Id BatchProcId = Database.executeBatch(SkillBatch);
        // System.debug('After batch, still in test: ' + SE.ToSkill__c);
        System.Test.stopTest();
        // System.debug('After batch, after test: ' + SE.ToSkill__c);

        System.assertEquals(ToSkill.Id, SE.ToSkill__c);
    }
}
```

The several `System.debug()`s that are commented out around `System.Test.StartTest()` were just for myself, to demonstrate that at ALL points in the testing class, the value I'm trying to update in the batch class remains unchanged.

I apologize for simply code-dumping everything, I really can't tell where the error lies.  My best guess is that something is wrong with the objects declared in the test class, or that `StartTest()` and `Database.BatchableContext` are doing something with scope I don't understand.

Comment: a good practice when testing datetimes is to use a Util.setNow() method and a Util.getNow() method in your classes and testmethods. The two methods share a static variable. Ifthe vraiable is null, Util.getNow() returns `system.now()` This way, you can set the "now" datetime in testmethods to be a constant and you can rely on that value in asserts

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I can't believe I was so blind.

```
global void execute (Database.BatchableContext BC, list<SkillEscalationChangeRecord__c> scope) {
    for (SkillEscalationChangeRecord__c record : scope) {
        record.SkillEscalation__r.ToSkill__c = record.ChangeToSkillTo__c;
    }
    update scope;
}
```

`Update scope;` updates a list of `SkillEscalationShangeRecord__c`s, rather than the `SkillEscalaltionChageRecord__c.SkillEscalation__r` that I was updating.  I assumed it would update all changes on referenced objects as well, but this is not the case.

Fixed with the following:

```
global void execute (Database.BatchableContext BC, list<SkillEscalationChangeRecord__c> scope) {
    for (SkillEscalationChangeRecord__c record : scope) {
        record.SkillEscalation__r.ToSkill__c = record.ChangeToSkillTo__c;
        update record.SkillEscalation__r;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are performing dml inside for loop don't think its a good approach.